# Excel issue related to SUMIFS of dates (start_date & end_date) per criteria (specific text)

Tags: excel, date

I have got 2 sheets:

1. "Sheet1" which contains [the date is with format "dd/mm/yyyy"]:

   ```
   0| A |   B    |     C    |    D     |
   1|ID |Duration|Start_date|End_date  |
   2|ALB|       3|01/01/2016|03/01/2016|
   3|DRA|       5|08/01/2016|12/01/2016|
   ```
2. "Sheet2" contains a detailed (per month days) timeline for the 2 IDs:

   ```
   0|    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |...|    M     |...|
   1|Date      |01/01/2016|02/01/2016|03/01/2016|...|12/01/2016|...|
   2|ALB       |          |          |          |...|          |...|
   3|DRA       |          |          |          |...|          |...|
   ```

In "Sheet2" by using "SUMIFS", I would like to split those dates per ID and as a result of that to get the following [for database I use the information provided in "Sheet1"]:

```
0|    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |...|    M     |...|
1|Date      |01/01/2016|02/01/2016|03/01/2016|...|12/01/2016|...|
2|ALB       |         1|         1|         1|...|          |...|
3|DRA       |          |          |          |...|         1|...|
```

I tried the following in [Sheet2, cell B2], but in both cases, a `#VALUE!` error appeared:

- ```
  =SUMIFS(IF(AND(B$2>='Sheet1'!$C:$C;B$2<='Sheet1'!$D:$D);"1";"");'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$3;'Sheet2'!B2)
  ```
- ```
  =SUMIFS(IF(AND("01/01/2016">="all Start_dates";"01/01/2016"<="all End_dates");"1";"");"all IDs";"single ID")
  ```

Where is my mistake? Or is there another way to achieve the required result?

Comment: Are there several entries on Sheet1 for ALB and DRA? It's not clear from the question. If not, then you wouldn't need SUMIFS.

Comment: Yes, there are a plenty of. I have just mentioned the first 2 in order not to be too much detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**: Use this array formula. Paste it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> :

```
={SUMPRODUCT(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=$A2,1,0),IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7<=B$1,1,0),IF(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7>=B$1,1,0))}
```

Or try [my new example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1RWFHdUFrUFZqQ1U)

Comment: Hello there! I have tried your suggestion. It works but only for the menthioned 2 examples. The problem is not caused by the absolute addresses (on row 6 I have got data which didn't appear in the concrete date in "Sheet2"). It requires some fine tunings. Could you please assist? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Yes of course, why not? Just tell other criterias, we will try fix it.

Comment: I didn't see any problem there. write briefly, please

Comment: Okay, here they are (please add the new info to the already provided above; Sheet1, startin at row 4, cell A):

ALB|4|22/03/2016|25/03/2016
ALB|7|15/05/2016|21/05/2016
DRA|2|07/05/2016|08/05/2016

In summary, ALB has got 14 days, DRA has got 7 days.
Once again, the expected result is, at the days in Sheet2 from the mentioned period, to return 1. And when the rows, represending the data for these 2 IDs, are summarised to have 14 and 7 as a total amount.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Ok, try my updated file, everything worked fine, just remember that day intervals in sheet1 should be in ascending order. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1THVIWlNNSHZMVXc

Comment: Hello, again! I saw you excel file and updated the formula as per my data. It works properly. Thank you for the spent time and efforts to help me in solving the issue. Just one more question - is there any way to perform the result if the data in Sheet1, Column C "Start_date" is not sorted into ascending way?

Comment: Thank you once again for the cooperating approach of yours! :)

Comment: If date is not sorted, `MATCH()` function doesn't work properly. If everything is ok, just check my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I just wanted to know whether there is an option for not-sorting. Thanks! You made my day! :)

Comment: Hello, again! I came back to the topic because I faced a problem. The already proposed solution earlier worked fine. But when 4 ID-s (for example) mention at the same time one and the same date, the formula takes and returns the first ID which has submitted it. I thought that INDEX & MATCH use the same logic as SUMIFS, not like VLOOKUP. How can I fix it up?

Comment: Hello, please, explain briefly your problem with examples

Comment: "Sheet1"

0| A |   B    |     C    |    D     |
1|ID |Duration|Start_date|End_date  |
2|ALB|       1|27/02/2017|27/02/2017|
3|DRA|       1|27/02/2017|27/02/2017|
4|VAS|       1|27/02/2017|27/02/2017|
5|BRA|       1|27/02/2017|27/02/2017|

Comment: "Sheet2" where the formula is located  [Instead of seeing the 4 entries on 27/02/2017, the formula populates only 1 out of 4. To be exact, for the 1-st entry (ALB)]
0|    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |...|    M     |...|
1|Date      |01/01/2017|02/01/2017|03/01/2017|...|27/02/2017|...|
2|ALB       |          |          |          |...|         1|...|
3|BRA       |          |          |          |...|          |...|
3|DRA       |          |          |          |...|          |...|
3|VAS       |          |          |          |...|          |...|

Comment: It is difficult to solve this problem with single excel formula

Comment: Okay, what is it your suggestion then?

Comment: Can we change the arguments in INDEX & MATCH part? I meant instead of looking for the exact date per ID-s to search for ID per dates?

INDEX("Columns from ID to Date from";MATCH("Date";"Columns from Date from to Date from";"Greater than");"Column ID")=ID

Comment: ok, I corrected my answer, but you should check my answer as accepted and vote)))

Answer (score 0):

If your dates in Sheet2 are in B2 to M2, then

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,"<="&B$2,Sheet1!$D:$D,">="&B$2,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A3)>0,1,"")
```

starting in B3.

Comment: Hello, there! Your proposal is not working properly. The reason is because it counts one additional day. I mean if ID "DRA" has got 2 days (from 08/05/2016 to 09/05/2016 included) the formula returns that 07/05/2016 is also added to the period. I think it requires a revision. Nevertheless, thank you for the help provided! :)

Comment: Yes you're right of course, there was a typo in the formula and C$2 should have been B$2. Will edit my answer.